# Stop my TicTacToe game when it is finished

Tags: android

I developed a simple game: TicTacToe. The problem is that: when the game is finished i want to stop it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Yes, you have to stop it when it's finished

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to do my Question ahah

Comment: How can i stop it?

Comment: Maybe you mean that you want the app to terminate itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exit an app on a button press or when game reaches a certain point you can use the following snippet:

```
public void onButtonPressed() {
  moveTaskToBack(true);
  android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
  System.exit(1);
}
```